# Probability of polynomials products to be bounded by a given bound

Tags: pr.probability, polynomials, norms, products

I am given a quotient ring $R=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\left< x^n +t\right>}$ for $t\in\mathbb{Z}$,
and two polynomials from $R$, $A$,$B$ and let $C$ to be there product.

Defining the norms $$\Vert A\Vert_{2}= \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\vert a_i\vert^2} \text{ and } \Vert A\Vert_{\infty}=\max_i \vert a_i\vert $$,

what is the probability of $\Vert C\Vert_{\infty}\leq \beta$ for a positive $\beta$ such that the $a_i$s and $b_i$s are selected uniformely random from $\{-1,0,1\}$.

the same question to the norm $\Vert \cdot\Vert_2$.

I have tried to do some numerical experiments but failed ...

Comment: Before asking for a probability, you should define a probability space. Also you seem to use $B$ for two different things.

Comment: thanks @BrendanMcKay